# Beginner Matplotlib, how to make random data for graph

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, numpy, matplotlib

I'm playing around with matplotlib trying to learn its features but one problem I am struggling with is making it randomly produce data to test my graph. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly here?

```
import numpy as np

labels = numpy.random.random_integers(0, high=1, size=10000)
x = numpy.random.random_integers(1, high=10, size=10000)
y = numpy.random.random_integers(1, high=10, size=10000)

plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.hist(x, label='1')
plt.hist(x[y==0], label='0')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('testRand.png')
```

Further to this, how can I distribute data within a range, for example if I want x to hold 10% 1's, 20% 2's, 70% 3's so this can be graphed and I can make my graphs look pretty/possibly hold meaningful distributions?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see anything "incorrect" with your code. Did you intend to use the `labels` sample for anything?  Also, `y==0` will be `False` everywhere because your lower limit for the `y` sample is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate samples from meaningful distributions, many are supplied, for example:

```
x = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)
```

Many more are in `scipy.stats`:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.gausshyper.rvs(a, b, c, z, size=10000)
```

To do something custom like what you want you can either create your own distribution with `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` or `rv_discrete`, where you can define whatever pdf or pmf you wish.

Or, a simpler hack for your example might be:

```
np.random.choice([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], size=10000)
```

[image: 1223333333]